# Using python requests to POST data with file

Tags: python, curl, file-upload, python-requests

I have the following working curl

```
curl -v -i -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -H "X-Authorization: 12345" -F "file0=@/path/to/image.jpg" -d 'jsonData={ "data": { "field1": 1, "field2": 2 } }' -X POST http://example.com/url/path
```

I am trying to make the exact same request in python and came up with the following

```
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'X-Authorization': '12345',
    }

    files = {
        'file0': ('/path/to/image.jpg',
                  open('/path/to/image.jpg', 'rb')),

    }

    file_post = requests.post('http://example.com/url/path',
                                headers=headers,
                                files=files,
                                data={
                                    "jsonData": {
                                        "data": {
                                            "field1": 1,
                                            "field2": 2,
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
```

The problem is that I'm getting a different response for curl and for python. Are these requests not equivalent or should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: tools to convert `curl` to `python` - [Convert curl syntax to Python, Node.js, PHP](https://curl.trillworks.com/) and [uncurl](https://github.com/spulec/uncurl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just pass in a Python dictionary without encoding it to JSON. Your curl post has JSON-encoded data for the `jsonData` form field, so your Python code needs to provide the same:

```
import json

headers = {'X-Authorization': '12345'}

files = {
    'file0': ('/path/to/image.jpg',
              open('/path/to/image.jpg', 'rb')),
}
file_post = requests.post(
    'http://example.com/url/path',
    headers=headers,
    files=files,
    data={
        "jsonData": json.dumps({
            "data": {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 2,
            }
        })
    })
```

By passing in a dictionary to `data`, each *value* that is an iterable, is seen as a sequence of separate values (so `{'data': ['foo', 'bar']}` is translated to `data=foo&data=bar`). You passed in a dictionary for the `jsonData` key, which is an iterable and thus treated a a sequence of values. Ultimately you only posted `jsonData=data`, nothing else.

By using a (JSON encoded) single value, you tell requests to pass that value directly, as the value for the `jsonData` key.

Using the `files` keyword argument triggers the right `Content-Type` header as well, it doesn't need setting manually.